# Powershell Creating New objects with Multiple Functions

Tags: arrays, object, powershell

So I've almost got my initial problem solved but I'm running into a brick wall here: I've a set of 3 variables (which will eventually become a lot more) that need to be formatted into a table. I've created functions for each variable and I can successfully combine two variables using the following code:

```
$pids = get-counter -listset process | get-counter -maxsamples 1 | select -expandproperty countersamples | where {$_.path -like "*\id process" -and $_.path -like $filter} | select cookedvalue | ForEach {$_.cookedvalue}
function GetMemoryUsage  { ...code here... }
function GetAppID { ...code here.... }
$combined = $pids | %{ $wapp = GetAppID $_
             $obj = new-object psobject
             $obj | add-member -name WP -type noteproperty -value $wapp
             $obj | add-member -name "Process ID" -type noteproperty -value $_
             $obj
        }
Write-Output $combined
```

My question is: How do I add GetMemoryUsage as an object here? I've tried using a function but it's not going so well. Mind you I don't want to use Hash Tables here as I believe they only working in v2 and I've still got machines running v1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the Process Id and memory consumption is what you're after then this should work for you:

```
Get-Process | Select Name,ID,WorkingSet
```

Comment: Have you checked the PrivateMemorySize property in the output of Get-Process?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

The key here was piping it out to an array successfully. I've had a lot of drawbacks here but you've got to work thru them.

```
$pids = get-counter -listset process | get-counter -maxsamples 1 | select -expandproperty countersamples | where {$_.path -like "*\id process" -and $_.path -like $filter} | select cookedvalue | ForEach {$_.cookedvalue}
function GetMemoryUsage  { ...code here... }
function GetAppID { ...code here.... }
$myresults = @()
$x = foreach ($ids in $pids) {
         $thisapp = GetAppID $ids
         $thismem = GetMemoryUsage $ids
         $robj = New-Object System.Object
     $robj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name WP -value $thisapp
     $robj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Memory -value $thismem
     $robj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Process -value $ids
     $myresults += $robj
}
$myresults | ft -auto
```

The great thing abou this method is that you can pipe in an infinite number of variables and as long as you can relate these to the array then you're in business.